# Index and search document having words with spaces in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

due to a particular document process production I have a bunch of documents with malformed words, having spaces within them. These could be important words to search for and for the moment I don't have the possibility to obtain another format of documents so, I want to know if there is any way to index the documents and find them anyway using correctly formed words in query time. For example I could have the word '**e ng i ne er**' in indexed document and I want to find it typing '**engineer**'.
Do you know ways of achieving that task in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to start from [NGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). Which tokenize only numbers and letters, so even using spaces it will be able to find a match.

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr! I went through the shingles path, mostly using [this example](https://gist.github.com/polyfractal/4542494) with some modifications. But I understand that it is essentially a variation of your proposal.